# Laravel mapping collections based on multiple conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a method on my model which I want to use to return a `true`/`false` given multiple conditions.

I have a collection of books, I then map over them. The conditions are:

1. I don't want to return a book that has a cancelled date attached to it.
2. Check if the genre has either `horror` or `truecrime`.

Each time I run it in my test it seems to return different based on running the entire test class or filter the individual test and I can't work it out.

```php
public function hasActiveBook()
{
    return $this->books->map(function ($bookMeta) {
        if ($bookMeta->cancelled !== null) {
            return false;
        }

        return in_array($bookMeta->genre, ['horror', 'truecrime']);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sample inputs and expected outputs please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the collection functions [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#)

```
return collect($this->books)
    /**
     * Checking
     * $bookMeta->cancelled !== null)
     */
    ->whereNotNull('cancelled')
    /**
     * Checking
     * in_array($bookMeta->genre, ['horror', 'truecrime'])
     */
    ->whereIn('genre', ['horror', 'truecrime'])
    /**
     * Checking if collection is empty or not
     */
    ->isNotEmpty();
```